# bdcsv.py returns "The datetime zone id '00:00' is not recognised"

Tags: bluedata, bluedata-3.7

I'm trying to run `bdcsv.py`:

```
$ sudo python /opt/bluedata/bundles/bluedata-epic-entdoc-minimal-release-3.7-2207/scripts/monitoring/bdcsv.py \
     -c localhost \
     -f cred.json \
     -s 2018/02/07-00:00:00 \
     -e 2018/02/07-23:59:59
```

I received the error below when using my own start and end values, so for this post I used the start and end values from the example in the [BlueData docs](http://docs.bluedata.com/37_downloading-usage-details).

Running the above returns the following error (I've formatted the json to make it more readable):

```
processing data for virtual node: bluedata-40 ...
error: {  
   "error":{  
      "root_cause":[  
         {  
            "type":"parsing_exception",
            "reason":"[date_histogram] failed to parse field [time_zone]",
            "line":1,
            "col":477
         }
      ],
      "type":"parsing_exception",
      "reason":"[date_histogram] failed to parse field [time_zone]",
      "line":1,
      "col":477,
      "caused_by":{  
         "type":"illegal_argument_exception",
         "reason":"The datetime zone id '00:00' is not recognised"
      }
   },
   "status":400
}
```

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same error occurs when running `bdusage.py`.

The time zone seems to be passed to the ElasticSearch query in the wrong format. In both scripts, you will find the following lines (I added comments inline for clarification):

```
tz = time.timezone / 3600 * -1           
if tz < 0:
    tzstr = str(tz).zfill(3) + ":00"     # negative tz will produce strings like "-06:00"
else:
    tzstr = str(tz).zfill(2) + ":00"     # positiv tz will return e.g. "01:00"
```

`tzstr` will later be included in the query. The error you described appears only if the time difference is >= 0 hours, because [ElasticSearch requires](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) the time zone be in a format like `+01:00` or `-01:00`.

Fix it by replacing the last line in above code like this:

```
tzstr = "+" + str(tz).zfill(2) + ":00"    # positiv tz will now return e.g. "+01:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to install tzlocal on the machine where I'm running the bdcsv.py script:

```
sudo pip install tzlocal
```